# Why use http module to set port as app.listen also sets port?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, server

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

// sets port 8080 to default or unless otherwise specified in the environment
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello world');
});

// Only works on 3000 regardless of what I set environment port to or how I set
// [value] in app.set('port', [value]).
// app.listen(3000);
app.listen(app.get('port'));
```

By using the above code we can set our node.js port.
But sometimes I find on many web-sites people are using http module to set the nodejs port

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),
  function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Will anyone tell when to which code?

Comment: It's a matter of preference. The express uses the http module in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Use `app.listen` function when you are using "express" node module.

Use `http.createServer(app).listen` function when you are using "connect" node module.